# Skype on Ubuntu 18.04 issues - doesn't start and logs me out

Tags: 18.04, skype, file-sharing

The Skype app on Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't start when using the Community Theme snap Wayland (*communitheme*) theme. It automatically takes me to the lock screen

[image]

Also, clicking on Skype's file sharing icon freezes the app; after a while it shuts down spontaneously. Drag and drop a file for sharing works.

Answer (score 8):

You probably aren't using the latest version of Skype. Try installing the Skype snap package with:

```
sudo snap install skype --classic
```

If that doesn't work try installing the latest version of Skype from the insider channel.

```
sudo snap install skype --classic --channel insider/stable
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me

Comment: The 2nd command with --channel insider/stable works for me now. Thank you!

Comment: First one worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue with XWayland](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1754693) on Ubuntu 18.04.

It will be fixed with a future HWE update (packages `linux-generic-hwe-18.04`, `xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04`, `xwayland-hwe-18.04`). But it remains unclear when this will actually happen.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked removing skype and installing it from official skype repository:

1. Add Skype Linux client repository

   ```
    echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
   ```
2. Install Skype public key

   ```
    wget https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY 
    sudo apt-key add SKYPE-GPG-KEY
   ```
3. Install the apt-transport-https package, if don't have one

   ```
    sudo apt install apt-transport-https
   ```
4. Install skype itself

   ```
    sudo apt install skypeforlinux
   ```